# how to keep all the desired input values while changing the inputs to buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the array is correct it should turn the input fields to `btn btn-success` buttons (works). Now comes the part I cannot seem to get past: They don't keep their value inserted into the input field. Example: You insert the word "hello" in an input field (and we assume the word "hello" is correct) and it then turns to a green button. However it does not keep it's value. How can I achieve this, but with multiple input fields?

The code looks like this:

```
}).on('blur', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();

            if(cValue === "") {
               return;
            }

            if (cValue === syllable) {
                correctSylls.push(cValue);
                console.log(correctSylls);
            }

            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').replaceWith(getCorrectBtn());
                S.addRight();
                S.playRight();
          }
```

I tried appending to the button `cValue`, but that didn't work (as expected).

The function that creates the success button:

```
function getCorrectBtn() {
var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
    'type': 'button',
    'id': "button" + CBC++
});

return correctBtn;
}
```

Here is the complete loop (how the input fields are created aswell):

```
$.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) { 
        if (!syllable || !syllable.trim().length) {
       // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
           return;
      }

        var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
        });

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('blur', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();

            if(cValue === "") {
               return;
            }

            if (cValue === syllable) {
                correctSylls.push(cValue);
                console.log(correctSylls);
            }

            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').replaceWith(getCorrectBtn());
                S.addRight();
                S.playRight();
          }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the next: When you insert data in an input field it evaluates it vs the JSON word. if it's correct it keeps it as an input field untill the array "Syllables" is filled out correctly (as you can see in the IF statement). However let's say the array contains 3 words therefore it has 3 input fields that should turn green when all the 3 input fields have been filled out correctly. However: How can I keep the value of the input fields when I change them to buttons?

Comment: Ok, I kind of get what you need. Can you add the code you got. html specially

Comment: I don't use HTML to create the input fields. I use a loop. Would it be fine to put that piece in ?

Comment: Yes, any code that you are using so I can help with a solution

Comment: You are using `replaceWith` which actually replaces your input with your new code. If there was a value associated with that input, it will be replaced with a new input that has no value. Also, why are you replacing an input with a button?

Comment: Editted the question with the part that loops through it and creates inputs based on the words in the array. @Leeish because once the array has been filled out correctly it will should end up being disabled. But when using "disabled" and btn btn-success you get a very weird looking input field. It basically should show the end-user that he or she successfully completed that part.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').replaceWith(getCorrectBtn(cValue));`

```
function getCorrectBtn(value) {
    var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
        'type': 'button',
        'id': "button" + CBC++,
        'value': value
    });
  return correctBtn;
}
```

This possibly should work.

Understand how `replaceWith` works. You aren't simply altering the existing input, you are replacing it. Since the value is data for the input, when you replace it, you are wiping out the data. So you must pass the data into the `getCorrectBtn` function and assign it to the new button.

Comment: I think it indeed works... but somehow they all turn into a white line without showing the actual button

Comment: When you inspect the HTML does it look right? Is it just the styling that is off?

Comment: No, it doesn't show anything at all. As if they just vanish. console.log() says it's undefined.